# Como mostrar un precio de acuerdo a que items de varios selects esten seleccionados con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario para conocer un presupuesto de acuerdo a que opciones de 3 selects escogan los usuarios.
[image: Como ven en la imagen, ese es mi formulario, hay 3 selects, "Que servicio le interesa" - "Milimetraje" y "Color"]

Lo que me gustaria hacer con javascript es un if que si por ejemplo en el select de servicio esta seleccionado la opcion "Ventana" y que en el select de Milimetraje este seleccionada la opcion "8mm" y que en el ultimo select de Color este seleccionada la opcion "Gris", al apretar el boton de Solicitar Presupuesto, muestre un precio en un div debajo de 450$. Alguna idea?

Lo que he intentado es muy de novato porque no domino aun javascript,

```js
$("#enviar").hide();

function calcularPrecio() {


    if ($("#milimetraje option[value='8mm']").attr('selected') && $("#color option[value='Gris']").attr('selected')) {
            $('#precio').html("450$");
            $("#enviar").show();
}

}
```

```html
<section class="col-md-12 text-center seccion-calculadora">
    <p>Ingrese sus valores para obtener un presupuesto <b id="aproximado-texto">apróximado</b></p>
    <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" role="form" id="formulario-presupuesto">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <select class="form-control" name="abertura" id="abertura" required>
                             <option disabled selected>¿Que servicio le interesa?</option>
                             <option value="Ventana Corrediza">Ventana Corrediza</option>
                             <option value="Puerta Corrediza">Puerta Corrediza</option>
                             
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <select class="form-control" name="milimetraje" id="milimetraje" required>
                             <option disabled selected>Milimetraje</option>
                             <option value="10mm">10 mm (Milimetros)</option>
                             <option value="8mm">8 mm (Milimetros)</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <select class="form-control" name="color" id="color" required>
                             <option disabled selected>Escoja el color</option>
                             <option value="Incoloro">Incoloro</option>
                             <option value="Bronce">Bronce</option>
                             <option value="Gris">Gris</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="largo" id="largo" placeholder="Largo">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="ancho" id="ancho" placeholder="Ancho">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="col-md-12 div-precio">
                        <p id="precio" data-placeholder="Precio apróximado"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    
                        <button class="btn btbn-succes btn-calcular" type="button" onclick="calcularPrecio()">Calcular precio</button>
                   
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-col-md-12 text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Solicitar presupuesto" name="submit" id="enviar" class="btn-enviar">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida, aprovecho a comentarte que la dinámica dle sitio es apoyar en dudas de código mostrado y partir de ahí

Comment: Hola! Agradeceríamos mucho si puedes agregar lo que haz intentado  (js funcionales y no funcionales de tu página, html) para poder ayudarte :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes simplemente crear una bandera booleana que he llamado `selStatus` donde evalúes el valor de ambos `select`. Será `true` solamente cuando tengan los valores que indicas y mostrará el precio, de lo contrario no.

```js
$("#enviar").hide();

function calcularPrecio() {
  var selStatus = $("#milimetraje").val() == "8mm" &&
    $("#color").val() == "Gris";
  if (selStatus) {
    $('#precio').html("450$");
    $("#enviar").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="col-md-12 text-center seccion-calculadora">
  <p>Ingrese sus valores para obtener un presupuesto <b id="aproximado-texto">apróximado</b></p>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" role="form" id="formulario-presupuesto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" name="abertura" id="abertura" required>
            <option disabled selected>¿Que servicio le interesa?</option>
            <option value="Ventana Corrediza">Ventana Corrediza</option>
            <option value="Puerta Corrediza">Puerta Corrediza</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" name="milimetraje" id="milimetraje" required>
            <option disabled selected>Milimetraje</option>
            <option value="10mm">10 mm (Milimetros)</option>
            <option value="8mm">8 mm (Milimetros)</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" name="color" id="color" required>
            <option disabled selected>Escoja el color</option>
            <option value="Incoloro">Incoloro</option>
            <option value="Bronce">Bronce</option>
            <option value="Gris">Gris</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" name="largo" id="largo" placeholder="Largo">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" name="ancho" id="ancho" placeholder="Ancho">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="col-md-12 div-precio">
            <p id="precio" data-placeholder="Precio apróximado"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

          <button class="btn btbn-succes btn-calcular" type="button" onclick="calcularPrecio()">Calcular precio</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row-col-md-12 text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Solicitar presupuesto" name="submit" id="enviar" class="btn-enviar">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Genial, funciono! Gracias!